# RMI Connect from local and remote

Tags: java, networking, rmi

I am trying to setup RMI in a way where I can connect from both the local machine that has a binded object and a remote machine. It seems like it can only be remote or local, at least from all the things I've tried.

```
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "public IP");

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT,
                    new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(),
                    new SslRMIServerSocketFactory());

            registry.rebind("world_server", World.getWorld());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using public IP, the local machine can't connect. If I change "public IP" to 127.0.0.1, remote machines can no longer connect. It will throw an error saying "connection refused on 127.0.0.1".

Is there any way to set this up so that both the local machine and remote can connect?

Thanks

Edit: Nevermind, fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to ensure that your local machine can access the public IP address. This is all about firewall rules rather than coding. And 'can't connect' isn't actually a problem description.

Comment: Please explain it under the question, how did you fix the issue...